# Hide GUID of WebExtension in title

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I'm about to create a [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) for Firefox. This browser plugin opens a small popup window and displays some information.

Unfortunately the opened popup is quite ugly since its window title looks like this:

`moz-extension://158ef65-...-...-...-...4af8 - My desired title - Mozilla Firefox`

[image: unwanted GUID in front of title]

Obviously, what I'm looking for is a way to hide the prepended string `mox-extension://` from the window title and just have it displaying the string `My desired title`. I think a Chrome extension would behave in the same way, but would prepend `chrome-extension://` instead. So I think my question would apply there, too.

The [`windows.create()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create) allows me to define a `titlePreface`, but this doesn't solve the problem. It just prepends another string but still leaves the unwanted extension prefix with the GUID in place.

[image: titlePreface doesn't help either]

I setup the browser action (the button which opens the popup) like this:

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  var url = browser.extension.getURL("foo.html");
  var creating = browser.windows.create({
    url: url,
    type: "panel",
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    titlePreface: "foo!" // "My desired title" is in the head of the foo.html file
  });
  creating.then(onCreated, onError);
});
```

So can anybody tell me how to hide the prefix containing the GUID?

Comment: I need to double check exactly what's been implemented for `titlePreference`. But, I suspect: It's not possible for you to affect this from a WebExtension. You're stuck with what Firefox gives you. You could open a normal browser window with a tab containing the URL within the extension.

Comment: That's bad news :( A full browser window would probably be even uglier ;)